# Center text relative to layout

Tags: android

I want to center a text inside a `TextView` relative to the parent layout and not relative to the textview.

Example in this code in want to center text `list_title` relative to my screen width:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
        android:layout_weight="75"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_title" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="90px"
        android:text="@string/filter"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/button_filter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Have you a solution?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, it's not a very good solution, but if you know your title lenght, you can add

```
android:paddingLeft="160dip"
```

to your textview.

Replace 160dip by 160 - lenght of your title / 2, it will be almost centered on all screens...

Edit: or if you want an other solution, you have to use relative layout.

Comment: How can i use relative layout to do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to replace your linear layout by a relativelayout like this: <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> and you have to put in it your textview with width to fill parent, weight to 0 and gravity to center, then you put your button in the relativelayout with weight to 1 and layout_gravity to right.

Comment: Yes relative layout is the solution

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with center the TextView and set its width to wrap_content:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_weight="75"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: It's doesn't work my text is center relative to layout without my button.

Comment: Can you explain further, do you want the button to be centered under the text? I think my answer was correct for the question you asked "I want to center a text inside a TextView relative to the parent layout and not relavent to the TextView"

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right then you want to put your TextView element in the middle/center of parent view?

Make your parent layout RelativeLayout and set TextView "Center in Parent" true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your xml:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this -

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/widget21"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@drawable/header"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/widget20" android:layout_gravity="bottom"


                    >
                        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/widget21"
                        android:layout_marginTop="37dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/widget20">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_header_text" 

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="24dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="@string/section_header_text" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" android:gravity="bottom"

                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"



                        ></TextView>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitEnd" />
                <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/retrieving_text"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:singleLine="false" android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
```